# Async в C++, два одинаковых потока работают вдвое дольше чем один

Tags: c++, асинхронность

Вот минимальный код воспроизводящий проблему:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <future>
#include <ctime>

using namespace std;

uint test(uint a, uint b)
{
    return a * b;
}

uint calculator(uint counter)
{
    while(counter>0)
    {
        test(2, 2);
        counter --;
    }
    return 1;
}

int main()
{
    clock_t begin, end;
    uint counter = 1000000000;
    begin = clock();
    auto t1 = async(launch::async, calculator, counter);
    auto t2 = async(launch::async, calculator, counter);
    uint a = t1.get();
    uint b = t2.get();
    end = clock();
    cout << "time of the iteration is " << (double(end - begin) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC) << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Если запустить только один из потоков - время выполнения 2,5 секунды. А если запустить оба потока - время выполнения 5 секунд. При этом в диспетчере устройств видно, что с двумя потоками одновременно два ядра процессора загружаются на 100%. Что я делаю не правильно? Вот опции компилятора: `g++ -pthread main.cpp -o temp`

Comment: *"оба потока"* - в приведенном коде потоки не фигурируют. Кроме того, есть подозрение, что измерения производительности производились без оптимизации.

Comment: Я имел в виду что если закомментировать строки с t2. Измерения времени работы проводились именно для этого кода

Comment: На VC++ 2019 в режиме `/Od` (иначе оптимизатор выбрасывает все вообще) не воспроизводится. Примерно 1.88 2 потока, 1.86 — 1 поток. Где и как запускали вы?

Comment: На относится к теме, но всё же: если скомпилировать со включённой оптимизацией, то функция `calculator` превратится в просто `return 1;`, т. к. внутренние вычисления не используются для получения результата.

Comment: Использую VSCode, все настройки по умолчанию, только добавил  "-pthread". Оптимизация отключена

Comment: VSCode — всего лишь среда, даже не компилятор. Мало ли, может, у вас процессор одноядерный? Или какие-то настройки не разрешают использовать больше одного ядра (я так понимаю, у вас Linux? в нем я не силен...).

Comment: Процессор 4 ядра без мультитрединга. Линукс, да. Компилятор g++. При запуске кода скомпилировнного с двумя потоками загружаются 2 ядра

Comment: async по умолчанию может запустить в отдельном потоке, но не обязан.

Comment: Вот ответ https://stackoverflow.com/q/10059239/644688 - все по спеке

Comment: @KoVadim, но я указал launch::async. Кроме того, я вижу по загрузке процессора, что запускаются два потока

Answer (score 0):

Сейчас увеличил счётчик втрое и измерил время вручную. Оказалось в обоих случаях одинаковое, т.е. `async` работает нормально.

Просто `clock()` выдаёт некорректное время, когда используется async.

Comment: `clock()` обычно выдает корректное время, просто Вы не хотите понимать, как он работает и применяете его не правильно. А он  суммирует всё время (все кванты времени), которое система "выдала" всем потокам Вашего процесса. Если Вы хотите получить реальное время выполнения, то и используйте соответствующие функции: например, можно использовать `omp_get_wtime()` из OpenMP, либо `gettimeofday()`, либо `std::chrono::steady_clock::now()`.